# The argument type 'JsObject' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'

Tags: flutter, dart

Heres when the error acquired, I wanted to change screen if the process is success and stayed if the process failed

```
    Status() {
  String rawJson =
      LG();
  Map<String, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(rawJson);

  String status = map["STATUS"];

  if (status == "Success") {
    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SPAL()),
          (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
    );
  } else {
    print("Failed");
  }
}
```

here's where the it is executed

```
ButtonWidget(
                text: 'Submit',
                onClicked: () async {
                  if (_emailing.currentState.validate() &&
                      _passwd.currentState.validate()) {
                    Status();
                    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                    prefs.setString('email', emailController.text);
                  }
                },
              ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't return `Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil()` and add the build context as param: `Status(context)`

Comment: What should i use?

Comment: Use what you use now but don' return it. Just call it. I.e remove "return". Try that.

Comment: this appears error: `The argument type 'JsObject' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'.`

Comment: What is the type of context? Show the full code where if is executed

Comment: the buildcontext needs to be passed to you status method

Comment: how to pass the it?

Comment: Status(context)